# Laravel ,Mongo , @foreach logic in view

Tags: mongodb, laravel, foreach

I have Laravel with Mongodb and inside collection document like this;

```
},
        "et_score": null,
        "starting_time": "13:00:00",
        "competition": {
            "active": true,
            "id": NumberInt("46"),
            "name": "Liga 1"
        },
        "awayTeam": {
            "venue_id": NumberInt("2454"),
            "name": "Team away -> Liga1",
            "coach_id": NumberInt("140772"),
            "twitter": ""
        },
        "homeTeam": {
            "venue_id": NumberInt("0"),
            "name": "Team home -> Liga1",

        },
        "home_score": NumberInt("1"),
        "starting_date": "2016-12-24",
        "away_score": NumberInt("1")
    }
})
```

.....

And my .blade has this;

```
....
   @foreach($data_user as $league)

        <table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>

         <thead><tr><th>{{$league{"competition.name"} }}</th></tr></thead>
            @endforeach

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                @foreach($data_user as $match)


                    <th>{{$match{"starting_date"} }}</th>
                    <th>{{$match{"starting_time"} }}</th>
                    <th>{{$match{"status"} }}</th>
                    <th>{{$match{"homeTeam.name"} }}</th>
                    <th>{{$match{"home_score"} }} : {{$match{"away_score"} }} </th>
                    <th>{{$match{"awayTeam.name"} }}</th>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
        </table>
.....
```

This print out table like this one ;

[table.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg0iP.jpg)

As you see I have all Teams in one "luega table" and would allocate team to "Team Home -> Liga1" to go to table Liga1 and also  "Team Home -> Super League" should be in Superliga etc.

I know that I missing some logic in @foreach but I do not have enough experience for such a thing to fix, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand exactly what you want to do, but from what I see they are opening or closing your foreach wrong, that generates badly the html, besides bad use of the model.

Review the following

```
@foreach($data_user as $league)
<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{$league->competition->name }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($data_user as $match)
        <tr>
            <th>{{$match->starting_date }}</th>
            <th>{{$match->starting_time }}</th>
            <th>{{$match->status }}</th>
            <th>{{$match->homeTeam.name }}</th>
            <th>{{$match->home_score }} : {{ $match->away_score }} </th>
            <th>{{$match->awayTeam.name }}</th>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hi Manuel, get error with your suggestion: Trying to get property of non-object  on line 4

Comment: The information is a result of the model, a collection, an array? Check that, or add more information to help you, but remember that you are closing the foreach wrong and generates HTML with errors

Comment: ErrorException in f1da8afe98aba2781763f1e975725bb2aaa771cf.php line 5:
Trying to get property of non-object to get property of non-object (View: /Volumes/WEB/test/CRUD-Laravel-5.3-with-MongoDB/resources/views/myhome.blade.php)

Comment: Show your code returns the information, is eloquent result, collection, array?

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand your question, what do you  exactly mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if more help if you see Model and controller

model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Moloquent;

class PrimaryModels extends Moloquent
{
    protected $collection = 'football.live';
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\PrimaryModels as Moloquent;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Input, Redirect;

class PrimaryController2 extends Controller
{
    function index(){
        return Redirect::to('myhome');
    }

    function pages($template){
        $getAllData = Moloquent::all();
        return view($template, ['data_user' => $getAllData]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

But if I go like this have sam prob that all teams are in all leagues

```
@foreach($data_user as $league)
    <table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{$league{"competition.name"} }}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($data_user as $match)
            <tr>
                <th>{{$match->starting_date }}</th>
                <th>{{$match->starting_time }}</th>
                <th>{{$match->status }}</th>
                <th>{{$match{"homeTeam.name"} }}</th>
                <th>{{$match->home_score }} : {{ $match->away_score }} </th>
                <th>{{$match{"awayTeam.name"} }}</th>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@endforeach
```